# Using Joomla 3 now submenu are shown

Tags: joomla, responsive-design, joomla-k2

I'm new here and sorry for my english but I'm italian.

I'm using Joomla 3, Protostar template and K2 component.

In my mainmenu, I've some submenus with more levels, but it shows only the first level.

I checked the module and I see that it's set to show from level 1 to ALL.

Changing the template does not solve the issue.

Also, in a local test, I see that with another template it does not show the first level of submenu....

Is there something wrong that I should know, using K2 and templates using bootstrap? (I'm building a responsive website).

Also, when I test the website in my smartphone, I click on the menu and it opens submenu, but I can't click on submenu voice, because it loads the main menu voice.

Comment: check that you have enabled the module parameter `Show Sub-menu Items`  or not.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla submenus have historically a hard time with cache enabled, I'm not sure if it was fixed in 3, but just for narrowing it down try disabling the module cache of the submenus and see if it helps.